# Do I have to refit a model before I use the Hayes plugin?

Tags: spss, fitting, amos

I'm running a mediation analysis where I'm testing if information sharing mediates the relationship between integrity and innovation. The data was sourced using surveys with the survey being on a likert scale.

Now I did the model fit using CFA in SPSS AMOS, and tested for composite reliability, convergent and discriminant validity. I did remove some survey items that had low factor loadings, and then I computed the variables in SPSS, where I took the remaining survey items that related to the construct, and merge them into one single variable to represent that construct - I did this for all 3 of my constructs in the diagram below.

Now, instead of doing a path analysis or a full structural model in SPSS AMOS, I would like to rather use the Hayes Process Plugin to test for mediation. For such a simple model, I don't need to use SEM / path analysis and would rather use Hayes. Do I have to refit the model before I do the mediation test using Hayes Process Plugin? I know that for a path analysis or full structural model, I would need to, but would I need to for Hayes given that I have already tested for fit under the CFA?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The observed-variable path model that you show is saturated (just identified) and will therefore trivially fit perfectly when run within the framework of path analysis. Therefore, an overall test of model fit (chi-square) is obsolete for this model.

However, it seems a bit odd and inconsistent to first work with latent variables (in CFA) and then go back to observed variables (sum scores). You may have reasons for this but I wonder why you would not also run your path model as an SEM with latent variables since you already conducted the CFA. The SEM path model with all three paths would have the same fit as the CFA with correlated factors.